# Making a grid view using PinLayout

Tags: ios, swift, gridview

Using https://github.com/layoutBox/PinLayout

I am trying to make a grid view. 
the view will contain an arbitrary number of columns and rows.

The rows will size to fit the content of the labels respecting the width of the superview and sizing height base on content, the text will need to be sticking to the top of the view this means that if one of the labels needs to be 100 point tall and the next one only need to be 50 it will have 50 pts of space below its self. basically this will create a top aliment instead of the center if the label was covering the full height. in layout I make it have a bottom constraint that is == 0 or greater.

So far all I get is a view container with all the rows at origin x=0 , y = 0

the rows are views that contains labels and they are stacked in a container view.

I put the rows in the inview (container / table), for the moment the labels are still set using layout constraint (at least until I get the rows to fill corectly).

```
if let previousView = inView.subviews.last
        {
            inView.addSubview(rowView)
            rowView.pin.below(of: previousView).horizontally().bottom().wrapContent(WrapType.vertically).width(100%)
        }
        else
        {
            inView.addSubview(rowView)
            rowView.pin.all().wrapContent(WrapType.vertically).width(100%)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read carefully the documentation of PinLayout. 
Please have a look at the [introduction example](https://github.com/layoutBox/PinLayout#introduction-examples).

> PinLayout doesn't use auto layout constraints, it is a framework that manually layout views. For that reason, you need to update the layout inside either UIView.layoutSubviews() or UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews() to handle container size's changes, including device rotation. You'll also need to handle UITraitCollection changes for app's that support multitasking. In the example above PinLayout's commands are inside UIView's layoutSubviews() method.

Comment: We kind of kept hacking at it and re-reading the doc, we did end up on making the view work. So we have fixed this a while back actually. :)